# the usage of comma, and what part of speech is "each" here?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, relative-pronouns, clauses

I have recently read a sentence in a story .

> The four of you may be proficient, **each** in your
>   own subject.

I wonder why is the comma used before  **each**.
Is the word  **each**  adverb or pronoun
in this sentence ?
Looking forward to your wisdom replies  ---

Comment: You're probably trying to accommodate some rule of thumb like 'never use a comma before a prowhatsit'. Here, 'each in your own subject' is a parenthetical (subclass: further detail provided: arguably a deleted resumptive modifier), and parentheticals usually (and certainly in this case) need setting off with one or two commas, parentheses, or dashes.

Comment: @TrevorD So it's a pronoun or an adverb then, right?

Answer (score 1):

In this case "each" is used as a pronoun and is the subject of the dependent clause. Edwin is correct that the comma is used because the clause is a parenthetical and requires punctuation to offset it from the rest of the sentence. It doesn't have to be a comma. The sentence could also have been written:

> [...] proficient-- each in your own subject.

or

> [...] proficient (each in your own subject).

If the sentence continued after the word *subject*, another punctuation mark would be used to indicate the end of the parenthetical:

> [...] proficient, each in your own subject, [additional content]

If I were writing a sentence like this I would use a comma rather than a different punctuation mark because the comma suggests a pause in speaking while other punctuation suggests other things (like a hasty additional comment with dashes or a quiet aside with parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

Good morning Naykhit,

I think "each" is a quantifier despite every, a kind of determiner.  Just like Italian, it's used as a singular countable noun.

I hope I draw you in the picture.

Regards,
Jack